# How to publish root application and sub applications under root application in IIS?

Tags: iis, deployment, url-rewriting, publish, subapplication

I have a root application (Angular Application) in IIS like "www.example.com". (Main Website)
I need to publish sub applications under "www.example.com" like "www.example.com/app1".

I have deployed the website under root ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) and created virtual directories under root like ([www.example.com/app1](http://www.example.com/app1)). I'm getting URL Rewrite errors.

I would like to know the necessary configuration settings need to achieve this.

Can someone please explain how to achieve this ?

Comment: If you are deploying the angular app as sub application. run this command ng build --prod --base-href /app1/. create application in iis under the site where you want to host the app. create separate app pool. and add below rule in the sub application config file: `<rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true"> <match url=".*" /><conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" /><add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" /></conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/app1/" />
        </rule>`

Comment: what error you are getting could you please share?